# Systemd nats.service file is throwing error

Tags: fedora, systemd

I install NATS as guid for Ubuntu. How To Install and Configure NATS on Ubuntu 16.04

I had used same instruction as this in Fedora 27 it was working.

But nats.service file is not working in Fedora 29

/etc/systemd/system/nats.service

```
[Unit]
Description=NATS messaging server

[Service]
ExecStart=/srv/nats/bin/gnatsd -c /srv/nats/gnatsd.config
User=nats
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I did `sudo systemctl start nats` and `sudo systemctl status nats`

It is showing

```
● nats.service - NATS messaging server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/nats.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-02-17 16:28:54 +0530; 1s ago
  Process: 6664 ExecStart=/srv/nats/bin/gnatsd -c /srv/nats/gnatsd.config (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 6664 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Feb 17 16:28:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: nats.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Feb 17 16:28:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: nats.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Feb 17 16:28:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped NATS messaging server.
Feb 17 16:28:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: nats.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 17 16:28:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: nats.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 17 16:28:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start NATS messaging server.
```

But `/srv/nats/bin/gnatsd -c /srv/nats/gnatsd.config` is working properly.

Comment: systemd is running the process as the `nats` user; are you?

Comment: Yes. It is there. user and group has assigned to the `/srv/nats` folder.

Comment: What is `/srv/nats/bin/gnatsd`? Does it exist? What are the permissions? What is the type of `file` that it is?

Comment: It is nats service executable file. It has permission to run as nats:nats.

Comment: [status=203/EXEC](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#id-1.20.8) says: `The actual process execution failed (specifically, the execve(2) system call). Most likely this is caused by a missing or non-accessible executable file`

Comment: is gnatsd a script or a binary?

Comment: This is works after disabling selinux.